# Latex : algorithm not display under correct section

Tags: positioning, algorithm2e

I'm using the `algorithm2e` package to put algorithm in my `Latex` documents.

In my document, I have something like this :

```
\section My algorithms
\subsection Algo 1
code for first algorithm
...


\subsection Algo 2
code for second algorithm
...

\subsection Algo 3
code for third algorithm
...

\subsection Algo 4
code for fourth algorithm
...
```

and so on.

The problem is that when producing the PDF, some algorithm are correctly displayed under their subsection, and some are displayed on other pages, not under the right section.

I get something like this :

```
1. My algorithms
1.1 Algo 1
    pseudo code for algo 1

1.2 Algo 2
    pseudo code for algo 2

1.3 Algo 3
1.4 Algo 4
---------------- next page -----------
    pseudo code for algo 3
---------------- next page -----------
    pseudo code for algo 4
```

[**WARNING**: the following links are broken are *should* be fixed by the OP]

Here is the full Latex source code : http://www.filedropper.com/demo_1
Here is the PDF I get : http://www.filedropper.com/demo_2

Is there a way to make sure the algo will stick with its subsection ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`algorithm` is a floating environment, just like `figure` or `table`.
Quoth [the manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithm2e/doc/algorithm2e.pdf):

> The optional arguments [Hhtbp] 
>   *[to the algorithm environment, U.S.]*
>   works
>   like those of ﬁgure environment. The H
>   argument forces the algorithm to stay
>   in place. If used, an algorithm is no
>   more a ﬂoating object. Caution:
>   algorithms cannot be cut, so if there
>   is not enough place to put an
>   algorithm with H option at a given
>   spot, LATEX will place a blank and put
>   the algorithm on the following page.

Comment: I feel so silly I didn't spot that ! Thanks !